# Assign option key via Ukelele

Tags: macos, keyboard, modifier-keys

My keyboard is a [Lioncast LK20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sld2P.jpg), which features no right `Windows` key. Instead there's the `FN` key.

In Windows that is no big problem, as I rarely use that button. In MacOS however, that means the right `Alt/Option` key is missing, which is bothersome.
I already used [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to map most keys to my liking. The one thing missing would be the right `Alt/Option`.

Key `110` (the [`Menu`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) key) would be perfect to be used as `Alt/Option` instead.
That button is assignable in Ukelele.

But is there a way to assign a modifier key like `Alt/Option` on it?

Comment: I read somewhere that Ukelele refuses to change modifier keys. Based on its own tutorial it seems like it's only interested in creating "dead keys" for inserting accents of foreign languages.